# Only run an INSERT query if a figure from an AJAX call is > than existing in db

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to only run an SQL `INSERT` query if the pageID (number) which is pulled through via an AJAX call, is more than what is already in the db.  A user essentially clicks on a next button, which shows the correct page content, then calls an AJAX POST request, which fires an SQL statement. Any guidance on the if checking statement would be appreciated as I have hit a brick wall.

**The Next button code:**

```
<a id="next" onclick="savePgID(1,2)">Next</a>
```

**AJAX call:**

```
function savePgID(moduleID, pageID){
    $.ajax({  
        url: "pageAJAX.php",  
        method: "POST",   
        data: {moduleID:moduleID, pageID:pageID},
        dataType: 'json',
      });
  }
```

**pageAJAX:**

```
<?php

session_start();
require 'scripts/db.php';
$studentID = $_SESSION['studentID'];

if(isset($_POST['pageID'])) {
    $moduleID = $_POST['moduleID'];
    $pageID = $_POST['pageID'];

    if() {
        // Here is where I want to check whether using the moduleID and 
        // pageID to check if the pageID in the db is less than the page 
        // user is on. Only if the pageID user is currently on, is 
        // greater than what they have in db, THEN run the below insert.
    } else {
        // INSERT Query into DB, this will update the pageID when user clicks next on module
        $stmt = $conn->prepare ("UPDATE `studentTakingModule` 
                        SET `pageID` = ? 
                        WHERE `studentTakingModule`.`studentID` = ? 
                        AND `studentTakingModule`.`moduleID` = ? ");    

        $stmt->bind_param("iii", $pageID, $studentID, $moduleID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
    }

}
?>
```

**NOTE** *** After an answer has been supplied, I have updated the code to the below, which now never fires the `INSERT` new pageID number into my DB, (even though the current pageID is more than the pageID number in the database):

```
<?php
session_start();
    require 'scripts/db.php';
        $studentID = $_SESSION['studentID'];

        if(isset($_POST['pageID']))
        {
            $pageID = $_POST['pageID'];
            $moduleID = $_POST['moduleID'];

            $stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT MAX(pageID) as `pageID`, `moduleID` FROM `studentTakingModule` WHERE `studentTakingModule`.`studentID` = ? AND `studentTakingModule`.`moduleID` = ? ");
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $studentID, $moduleID);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if(!empty($result)) {
                $dbPageID = $result[0]['pageID']; 
                //$dbPageID2 = $row['pageID']; 

                if($pageID > $dbPageID) {
                    echo "You have reached the update statement";
                    // INSERT Query into DB, this will update the pageID when user clicks next on module
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare ("UPDATE `studentTakingModule` SET `pageID` = ? WHERE `studentTakingModule`.`studentID` = ? AND `studentTakingModule`.`moduleID` = ? ");    
                    $stmt->bind_param("iii", $pageID, $studentID, $moduleID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: What is the issue you have faced ?

Comment: @Ajith it's the `if` statement within the pageAJAX.php file, I need to check if the current page number a user on is more than what they already have saved in the db, and if so, then run the insert query.

Comment: Have you checked out `INSERT on Duplicate UPDATE` syntax

Comment: @T.C I think you should make a select query and compare the value with the select result

Comment: @Ajith run a select query inside of the `if` statement?

Comment: @T.C I have added a sample code for checking your condition, I hope that will helps you

Comment: @Ajith May I run something by you with the query I have built which doesn't seem to run for this?

Comment: @T.C Yes please let me know your doubt ?

Comment: I do not think the `$dbPageID = $result[0]['pageID']; ` line is pulling anything out of my db, therefore the `if` statement isn't firing, which then means that if the `$pageID = $_POST['pageID'] > $dbPageID `, my insert does not run.

Comment: You can check a result empty condition ,I ll update my answer now

Comment: @Ajith I will update my question with what I am trying (with the insert never firing anymore) for you to see exactly what I have done....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a sample condition check using the followin code

```
<?php
.........
// Get the current maximum pageID value for the selected student and module ID 
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT MAX(pageID) as pageID FROM studentTakingModule
        WHERE `studentTakingModule`.`studentID` = ? 
        AND `studentTakingModule`.`moduleID` = ? ");    

$stmt->bind_param( $studentID, $moduleID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if(!empty($result)){
    $pageID = $result[0]['pageID'];

    // If the new pageID is greater than the largest pageId value in DB
    if($pageID < $_POST['pageID']){ 

    }else{

    }
} else { // You can Insert without checking the max pageID value, Since it is a new one

}
.......
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

query and store the latest page id in a hidden input element

```
<input id="stored_page_id" type="hidden" value="$pageId">
```

or

better store the pageId in **session**.

now get the value of this hidden input and call `savePgID` method only if the `pageID > stored_page_id`, this way you will not end up calling the Ajax without any reason as you have already put the check.

otherwise you will unnecessarily call the Ajax request its better to put a check at the client side.

Comment: What if multiple users are doing this? What if someone tampers with that ID? As a hint, such data could better be stored in a session